# C++ Pure Virtual with a header definition and cpp implementation is throwing unresolved external symbol

Tags: c++

I am getting the following error:

> error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: virtual class AElementActor * __cdecl ElementFactory::CreateElement(int,int,int)" (?CreateElement@ElementFactory@@UEAAPEAVAElementActor@@HHH@Z)

with the following layout:

**IElementFactory.h**

```
struct IElementFactory
{

public:

    virtual AElementActor* CreateElement(
        int NeutronCount,
        int ProtonCount,
        int ElectronCount) = 0;

};
```

**ElementFactory.h**

```
#include "IElementFactory.h"

class ElementFactory : public IElementFactory
{

public:
    
    AElementActor* CreateElement(
        int NeutronCount,
        int ProtonCount,
        int ElectronCount) override;

};
```

**ElementFactory.cpp**

```
AElementActor* ElementFactory::CreateElement(
    int NeutronCount,
    int ProtonCount,
    int ElectronCount)
{
    // ...
}
```

If I move the definition to the header file for CreateElement, the program then compiles correctly:

**ElementFactory.h updated**

```
#include "IElementFactory.h"

class ElementFactory : public IElementFactory
{

public:
    
    AElementActor* CreateElement(
        int NeutronCount,
        int ProtonCount,
        int ElectronCount) override
    {
        // ...
    }

};
```

What gives?

Must pure virtuals be defined by the header or atleast, all in the cpp file?

Comment: Is this just a standard vcproj project?

Comment: It's an Unreal Engine solution. It's a module separate to the main game module. From your question, am I right in thinking that it should be possible then?

Comment: Are you sure ElementFactory.cpp is being compiled and linked as part of the project?